# preg_match_all regex value in between two tags

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I'm trying to build out a preg_match_all so I can use the array, but the problem is that I can't refine my regex to work.

An example input would be:

```
#|First Name|#
This text shouldn't be caught
#|Second Value|#
```

First Name and Second Value should both be in the array.

Here's what I've tried:

```
preg_match_all('/\#\|(.*?)\|\#\]/',$html, $out);
```

and

```
preg_match_all ("/^#\|*\|#*$/i", $html, $out);
```

Comment: It doesn't? What does `var_dump($out)` show for the first regex? What about if you removed the `\]` from the first regex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first is about right, it only contains `\]` near the end which breaks what you want. Using

```
/\#\|(.*?)\|\#/
```

does give me correct results, with the matches in `$out[1]`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this regexp :

```
/\#\|(.*?)\|\#/
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
preg_match_all('/#\|(.*?)\|#/', $html, $out);
```

Escaping # should not be needed. To specify no # between #'s, you might also use

```
preg_match_all('/#\|([^#]*)\|#/', $html, $out);
```

Answer (score 0):

a couple of things, you need to add the '.' character in between your bars. This character means match any character, without it you are saying match zero or more '|' characters. you also need to add the m modifier for multiline matching.

```
/^#\|.*\|#$/im
```

Comment: You forgot the capture expression (.*). Also, the i flag is superfluous, since there are no case sensitive characters in the regexp.